# Calculate and plot prediction intervals following logistic regression in Stata

Tags: stata, logistic-regression

I have a dataset in Stata 12 which consists of three columns (more or less):

1. date
2. binary outcome (0/1)
3. freq (number of subjects)

So a slice of the dataset might look like:

```
      date   outcome   freq
2016-03-04         0      9
2016-03-04         1      3
2016-03-05         0     11
2016-03-05         1      2
etc.
```

There are measurements for most days (although I have purposely removed the sparse data that occurs at weekends).

There appears to be a nice seasonal variation so I've calculated sin and cos variables using sin(2*pi*date/365) and cos(2*pi*date/365), and I've run a logistic regression model including time variables as continuous variables:

```
logit outcome c.date c.sin c.cos [fw=freq]
```

Following the logistic regression, I can calculate the probability of a positive outcome, the linear prediction (i.e. log odds) and the se of the linear prediction using:

```
predict phat
predict lohat, xb
predict se, stdp
```

Using Python and Pandas, I've calculated the odds and probability of the outcome on each day. When I plot these values against the predicted point estimates created using the logistic regression model it looks pretty good. However, I'd like to be able to calculate a prediction interval for the linear prediction conditional on date. I can readily calculate a confidence interval for the linear prediction (e.g. http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/prediction-confidence-intervals/) and I thought it would be straight-forward to calculate a prediction interval but I can't find a method to do it in Stata.

Does the lack of the necessary output suggest it's not possible?

If it is possible, what is the best method to estimate upper and lower prediction intervals following logistic regression in Stata?

Comment: Do you mean a prediction interval or a confidence interval? You might also modify your question with the Stata version constraint.

Comment: So if this was linear, you could use `stdf` option on predict; since it is a logit i think you need to investigate `predictnl`

Comment: @dimitriy-v-masterov I've added Stata version (Stata 12) to the question. The question says that I can calculate a confidence interval but I want to calculate a prediction interval.

Comment: @user1718097 I don't think this is possible. There's vehement disagreement on whether PIs make sense for logit models, and this would be off-topic here. Try Statalist or CV, and augment your question with formulas once you figure that out.

Comment: @dimitriy-v-masterov I'll try Statalist. Thanks.